# Excel - Pivoting the data with same column names

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table as follows:

```
  Date  |2021-01-01|2021-01-02|2021-01-03|.....|2021-01-08|2021-01-09|
Product |  Friday  | Saturday |  Sunday  |.....|  Friday  | Saturday |
--------|----------|----------|----------|-----|----------|----------|
   A    |  361278  |  439083  |  410921  |.....|  390020  |  422332  |
   B    |  422332  |  390020  |  410921  |.....|  439083  |  361278  |
```

The original data has only dates as shown in the first row, but I'm trying to sum the revenue based on the day of the week. When I pivot this table (after excluding the first row with dates, and using the row with days as column headers), I'm not getting the sum for all fridays together. Instead the column headers in the pivot are shown as Friday, Friday2, Friday3 etc.

In the pivot table, I want all the fridays to be summed into one column, all the saturdays into one column etc.

How can I do this? Please help me.

Comment: Do you need a pivot table? You could do this with a SUMIFS formula.

Comment: First you need to Unpivot the data; then repivot by day of the week.  Easily done with Power Query.

Comment: @Isolated SUMIFS alone won't be helpful as there are multiple criteria in rows and columns. Maybe SUMIFS with OFFSET could help. I know one more way, i.e. to use SUMPRODUCT. But then again, I'm just wondering if there's an easy way to do this in Pivot Tables.